# How do I send a TXT file in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, file, discord.js, txt

How do I send a txt file in discord.js as an Attachment?
Like this: [image]

I have tried the following code:

```
let content = nsOpts.Tcontent
fs.writeFileSync('./nosleep.txt', content)

let atc = new discord.MessageAttachment('nosleep.txt')

interaction.channel.send('here ya go,', { files: [atc, 'nosleep.txt', './nosleep.txt', 'attachment://nosleep.txt']})
```

But the bot only sends the message, not the file.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
let content = nsOpts.Tcontent;
let atc = new discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from(content), 'nosleep.txt');
interaction.channel.send({ files: [atc] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var atc = fs.readFileSync('./nosleep.txt', {"encoding": "utf-8"});
```

Comment: doesn't, work. I still get the message without the file as the attachment ;(