# Discord.js v14 sending a file attachment via data url

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanted to send a long text, so I tried to send it as a file.
But I can't create a file (I'm going to use free Heroku)

I think it would be good to use data url.
But, it isn't working

```js
//(slash command builder, ... , execute(interaction){)
    const File_ = { attachment: "data:text/text;charset=UTF-8;base64,4p2k77iO", name: "data.txt" };
    await interaction.reply({files: [File_] });
```

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\\(project folder)\\data:text\text;charset=UTF-8;base64,4p2k77iO'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\(project folder)\\data:text\\text;charset=UTF-8;base64,4p2k77iO'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a data string (which I question if discord even supports), you can try using [buffers](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers/). This should store your text in RAM instead of disk

[Heres an answer that shows you how to use them with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73193869/14688730)